# C++0x allocators

Tags: visual-c++, scope, c++11, allocator

I observed that my copy of MSVC10 came with containers that appeared to allow state based allocators, and wrote a simple pool allocator, that allocates pools for a specific type.
However, I discovered that if `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0` the MSVC vector creates a proxy allocator from the passed allocator (for iterator tracking?), uses the proxy, then lets the proxy fall out of scope, expecting the allocated memory to remain.  This causes problems because my allocator attempts to release it's pool upon destruction.  Is this allowed by the C++0x standard?

The code is roughly like this:

```
class _Container_proxy{};

template<class T, class _Alloc>
class vector {
     _Alloc _Alval;
public: 
    vector() {
        // construct _Alloc<_Container_proxy> _Alproxy
         typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other 
                 _Alproxy(_Alval);
        //allocate
        this->_Myproxy = _Alproxy.allocate(1);
        /*other stuff, but no deallocation*/
    } //_Alproxy goes out of scope

    ~_Vector_val() {    // destroy proxy
        // construct _Alloc<_Container_proxy> _Alproxy
        typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
                 _Alproxy(_Alval);
        /*stuff, but no allocation*/
        _Alproxy.deallocate(this->_Myproxy, 1);
    } //_Alproxy goes out of scope again
```

Comment: Is your allocator `CopyConstructible`?  I.e. can you copy construct it have the copy deallocate memory that the original allocated?

Comment: It is move constructable, but the "copy constructor" is the same as the default constructor.  However, in this case, I'd need the _origional_ to deallocate memory that the _copy_ allocated, which is far trickier.  Though I'm considering it.

Comment: Perhaps showing what the allocator looks like would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the giant table of allocator requirements in section 17.6.3.5, an allocator must be copyable. Containers are allowed to copy them freely. So you need to store the pool in a `std::shared_ptr` or something similar in order to prevent deletion while one of the allocators is in existence.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but can you provide the section in the standard that specifies this requirement?

Comment: oh, there it is: `X a1(a); Shall not exit via an exception.
post: a1 == a` and `X a(b); Shall not exit via an exception. post: Y(a) == b, a == X(b)`  Hmm.  I'll rethink things then.

Comment: I overlooked the post requirements.